# Spring Boot Java8 Microservice Simple Message Subscription service

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jms, microservices

I am new to Microservice and JMS likes to know how can I

- create a subscription
- read the subscription

Using Spring Boot and JMS

Answer (score 2):

To get started with Spring Boot and JMS use this getting started guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Once you have that sorted then adding the microservices is just a matter of adding the Spring MVC and Rest components which you could first experiment as a standalone project and then integrate with the JMS application.

To get started with Spring Book and Microservices use the getting started guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: The request Mapping or@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + email + ">");
    } // OR this method will receive the messages ?

Comment: After creating a Rest whether its controller or the Message Driven Pojo will listen to the request .The workflow from Controller to invoke @JmsListener is my doubt

Comment: Why would you like the @Controller to invoke the @Jmslistener? Or what problem are you trying to solve? Usually the JmsListener would read the queue and persist the resulting transaction to a data store and the Controller would read the data store for committed transactions.

Answer (score 0):

JMS not part of Java SE.  You need Java EE or Spring.

I'm not sure queues are the best way to solve the problem.

I'd recommend Spring Boot.

Subscription maintenance isn't something that the queue would do.

A simple REST service would manage this nicely.  You'll need a persistence layer to save subscription information.

Comment: I m using Spring Boot , and I know Spring Rest , but I am confused on creating a subscription using Rest, Any tutorials or links will be helpful

Comment: You're assuming that you need a queue. You

Comment: An attempt on your part will get you further. Write the API you need for subscriptions and messages in terms of HTTP verbs.